# How to act on the currently highlighted selection of expand region mode in a function?

Tags: evil, text-editing, defun

I am using `er/expand-region` in doom-emacs on Mac OS. I would like to combine yanking and expanding a region in a function, that is, automatically yank the selection of `expand region` with `evil` after expanding a region `x` times.
I've tried a few things, but they all seem not to work as intended.